# Find name in array (JSON)

Tags: swift

```
[{
  "participantId" : 1,
  "player" : {
    "summonerName" : "8eautiful",
  }
},
{
  "participantId" : 2,
  "player" : {
    "summonerName" : "test",
  }
}]
```

How do you know if this array contains the name "test"?

using swiftyjson

Comment: What did you try so far? You should use `Codable` instead of `SwiftyJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

If json is an `Array`

```
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    if subJson["player"]["summonerName"] == "test" {
        print("Array contains the name test")
    } else {
        print("Array does not contain the name test")
    }
}
```